# is every edge of a zonotope a generator?

Tags: convex-geometry, polytopes, discrete-geometry

Given a Zonotope $Z \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, with generators $G \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$.

Every facet is a $d-1$ polytope. And I'm wondering is it true that every edge of the facets is one generator with some positional offset?

Since every vertex is in the form of $\sum_{i \in G} = \lambda_i i, \lambda_i \in \{0, 1\}$, and the edge is difference between two vertices, so every edge has to be some sum of a subset of generators. But does the difference has to be exactly one generator?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. And here is the proof:

If the edge is composed of more than one generator, one can always add an extra vertex correspondingly.

Comment: I would say this differently. You are not "adding a vertex" when the difference between vertices is composed of more than one generator. That difference is an internal  diagonal of some face, not an edge of a facet.

Comment: maybe separate the edge into more than one edges?

Comment: If no two generators are collinear then every edge is a parallel translation of one of the generators.